# How to know which row makes error while debugging loop in visual studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Let's say I have a loop which contains 1000 rows of data customers retrieved from a table in database. There's an error which is caused by some null fields on the data. How can I hit the  row that causes the error without needing to go to every item while debugging the loop?

Edit: the caused by null fields is only an example. It can be caused by other problems. I asked this because I encountered some problems related with data inside the loop  in the past. So far ...I think vivek's advice to include try catch temporary is good.

Comment: What database technology are you using? Also include some relevant code.

Comment: Probably a good idea to post the loop you are describing, I assume this is in code, if you are using ADO then maybe iterate a SqlDataReader using `reader.Read()` that will blow up on the row that's a problem. Also make sure you have Visual Studio set up to break on all exceptions Debug -> Windows -> Exceptions -> Common Language Runtime Exceptions checked in VS 2017

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Turn on handle CLR exceptions in the exceptions window. The debugger will break when the exception occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only for debugging purpose, put `try...catch` inside your loop. Put breakpoint on catch block. Whenever an exception occurs, you will have access to current row.

Don't forget to remove `try...catch` from the loop once debugging is done.

Comment: Thanks...this makes sense

Answer (score 2):

do u know the data Field casuing the null if so check where null records as follows if you go through Managment studio

Select * from Datatable where [Fieldname] isnull

IF c# loop just user try catch and Debug.print to record the record number.